# Reading a value from html5 session storage and using in animation not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am having this trivial issue with animation and wonder if I am plugging things the right way. I would appreciate it if you can share your thoughts on this. on JQuery initialization, I am saving a value as string via 'sessionStorate()' which I am then trying to use it for animating a div. Here is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
     sessionStorage.setItem('topVal','200');

     $("#myDiv").animate({

         'top' : sessionStorage.topVal
      },1000, function()
      {
          alert("ANIMATION DONE");
      });   
  });
```

If I to hard code the value instead of calling the 'sessionStorage.topVal'then div animates without any issues otherwise it doesn't. My utmost thoughts were that things are being fired up way too fast and therefore the animate() function is not able to catch the 'sessionStorage.topVal'. I wonder if I should employ a setTimeOut() to delay or just use delay(). I am not certain whether these are good practices or there are other ways to get it going. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works just fine for me.

See http://jsfiddle.net/GuHdf/